# CCTimer nil reference crash when 64bit

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

App using : `cocos2d-iphone rc5 , cocos2d`

My app has a problem with `CCTimer` `nil` refrence crash.

The problem is:

- debug mode is OK
- Release Mode 32 bit OK
- Release Mode 64 bit **Crash**

So I've checked `timer` if it's `nil`.

On this image you can see the `timer` is `nil` in debug mode in xcode

Please this Image [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BlQ02zZCcAA2T0j.png:large) with the `nil` error.

code :

```
if(timer != nil) {
 [some code]
}
```

I think [some code] won't run but [some code] will.

I can't understand why run in `64bit`. only `32bit`, `debug` mode is ok

That code `CCScheduler.m` in cocos2d-iphone class

And If statement is I added for check

[CCScheduler.m]https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/v3.0/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m link

Comment: i tried compiling [some code] and it does not !

Comment: Is `timer` a strong pointer?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg did you run xcode simulator 64bit mode?

Comment: You're welcome! Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @Winston yes,solved only crash , remove `arm64` in Valided Archetecture inXcode Setting  but couldn't solved 64bit mode

Comment: I've done that with a few of my apps that didn't work with arm64 either.

Comment: @Winston I've post problem to  cocos2d-iphone github link[https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/issues/704] have good time!

Comment: You too and thanks for the link!